# Объединить sql запрос в Access

Tags: sql, база-данных, ms-access

Есть первый запрос:

```
SELECT E.ID, SecondName AS Фамилия, FirstName AS Имя, Phone AS Телефон, P.Title AS Должность
FROM (Employee AS E INNER JOIN Position AS P ON E.PositionID = P.ID)
```

и второй:

```
SELECT  E.SecondName AS Фамилия, E1.SecondName AS Наставник
FROM Employee AS E INNER JOIN Employee AS E1 ON E.MentorID = E1.ID;
```

Не добавить второй запрос в первый через JOIN

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.ID, E.SecondName AS Фамилия, E.FirstName AS Имя, E.Phone AS Телефон, P.Title AS Должность, E1.SecondName AS Наставник
FROM (Employee AS E INNER JOIN Position AS P ON E.PositionID = P.ID) INNER JOIN Employee AS E1 ON E.MentorID = E1.ID;
```